# how to redefine atan2 function from -inf to inf in matlab?

Tags: matlab, phase, atan2

I have a rotating vector `R(x(t), y(t))` and I want to find an angle as a function of time. The `atan2` is determined between `-pi` and `pi`, however it is inconvenient for me to analyse all dynamics. So, is there any way to expand `atan2` from `-inf` to `inf`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I guess you are searching for the function [unwrap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html). This will correct all the `2 pi` jumps you get when your vector rotates through the negative x-axis. You use it like so:

```
t = linspace(0,3,1000);
x = cos(2*pi*t);
y = sin(2*pi*t);
phi = atan2(y,x);
unwrapped_phi = unwrap(phi);
plot(t, phi, t, unwrapped_phi)
xlabel('time (s)')
ylabel('angle (rad)')
legend('wrapped angle','unwrapped angle')
```

[image]

Comment: This command does not work if the jump is less than 2pi.  For example, one of the vector coordinates abruptly changes sign.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [phase unwrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase). Matlab has a 1D solution ready, see [unwrap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) for more details.